# Trying to use fabric to check out a git repository to a subdirectory

Tags: git, fabric

I'm using fabric to automate branch creation.  My problem is I don't know the branch name before the function is called, and fabric doesn't work with cd.

How can I tell git that the target directory is going to be one level lower?

Fabfile:

```
def new_branch(branch_name):
    local('mkdir ' + branch_name)
    local('git clone /var/www/finance ' + branch_name)
    local('git checkout HEAD ./' + branch_name + ' -b ' + branch_name)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[localhost] local: mkdir test
[localhost] local: git clone /var/www/finance test
Cloning into 'test'...
done.
[localhost] local: git checkout HEAD ./test -b test
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 128) while executing 'git checkout HEAD ./test -b test'

Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use path parameters with git. Parameters are verified with git version 1.7.9.5.

```
local('git --git-dir ' + branch_name + '/.git --work-tree ' + branch_name + ' checkout HEAD -b ' + branch_name)
```