# Convert Jenkins pipeline script code into Python

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need some assistance to convert some Jenkins pipeline script code to Python. Reason for converting this code is that I have ssh to a remote host using Febric in Jenkins pipeline and I need to run pipeline script inside Febric which is Python based. Below is the sample code which I need to convert. Thanks

```
    git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: ‘xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx’, poll: false, url: 'ssh://git@xxxx.yyyy.net:port/path/project.git'
    def nodeHome = tool name: 'NodeJS 8.9.4', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'
    env.PATH = "${nodeHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    try {
        dir(‘project/test’) {
            sh(“docker ps -a”)
        }
    } 
    catch {
        // catch error
    } 
    finally {
        // finally
    }
```

Comment: Good luck. I hope you are able to do it on your own.

Comment: This question as is isn't likely to garner a lot answers (consider reviewing [ask]): it's very broad, and doesn't show any attempt we can build upon. There isn't going to be a tool that converts Groovy Jenkinsfile script tasks into a [fabric](https://www.fabfile.org) script. Instead, consider each _step_ of the `Jenkinsfile` and _what it does_. For instance, the first line checks out a git repo: [here's a question and answer about how to do that with fabric!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297889/trying-to-use-fabric-to-check-out-a-git-repository-to-a-subdirectory)